# HighCharts - Graph axis starting BEFORE first data point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using HighCharts to produce some graphs.

For some reason the graph axis do not start at 00:00 (which is the earliest data point in this case) but instead start from 23:00, which seems odd.

I have tried setting the `pointStart` option to the earliest data point but this doesn't help either.  I set the property like so:

```
options.plotOptions.series.pointStart = time;
```

Here is an image showing the issue:

[image]

Comment: When you removed startOnTick did your labels still start at 00:00?

Comment: I've got a problem where my labels start after the 1st point, but if I say startOnTick it starts before. I can't get it to start on the correct start time

Comment: I suggest posting on the highcharts forum, they are pretty good there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I had the `startOnTick` property set which, according to the documentation, may result in padding at the start.  I removed this property and it all works nicely now.